# Ruby and duplicate fields in mongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have problems with multiple fields that have the same name.

Let's consider the following code:

```
    mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
    db = mongo_client.db("mydb")
    coll = db.collection("test")
    coll.remove

    #create an entry
    customer = {:id => 321, :name => "test customer"}
    coll.save customer

    #find the entry and modify it
    customer = coll.find(:id => 321).to_a.first
    customer[:name] = "test customer 2"
    coll.save customer

    #find again and print
    customer = coll.find(:id => 321).to_a.first
    pp customer
```

The output is as expected:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('52e254c5990300785b000001'),
"name"=>"test customer 2",
"id"=>321}
```

But *robomongo* shows that there are now two *name* fields:
[image]

That is strange.

So my two questions are:

1. How can I repair my data base?

   - Repairing means: Iterating through all documents; test which of the two equally named fields is the one I want to keep; delete the wrong field and save the document again.
   - The problem here is that I cannot access both equally named fields because the document is mapped into a ruby hash...
2. How can I prevent the situation in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but both fields are there.
Because:

 1. In my real life example this duplicate field is large binary data. So I can see it in the size of the mongoDB files themselves.

 2. If I change the last *find()* call to *find(:name => "test customer")* it finds the document and prints exactly the same output as I've posted above.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with robomongo but with the MongoDB driver that Ruby uses. See my more precise answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot directly answer your questions but can give an explanation why you only see one field with "name" in your Ruby program whereas Robomongo shows both fields:

Have a look at the "**Field Names**" section on this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

**It says:**

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most
>   MongoDB interfaces, however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g.
>   a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need
>   to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same
>   name, see the driver documentation for your driver.
>
> Some documents created by internal MongoDB processes may have
>   duplicate fields, but no MongoDB process will ever add duplicate
>   fields to an existing user document.

So it looks like your MongoDB for Ruby does map a a document into a hash structure that doesn't support duplicate field names.

Maybe temporarily switching to the driver that Robomongo uses can help fixing your problem. After that you can return to using MongoDB.

Depending on your version of MongoDB I think you can prevent duplicate field names in a document by passing `--objcheck` to the `mongod` process.

**Excerpt from the manual:**

> --objcheck Forces the mongod to validate all requests from clients upon receipt to ensure that clients never insert invalid documents
>   into the database.  For  objects  with  a high degree of sub-document
>   nesting, --objcheck can have a small impact on performance. You can
>   set --noobjcheck to disable object checking at run-time. Changed in
>   version 2.4: MongoDB enables --objcheck by default, to prevent any
>   client from inserting malformed or invalid BSON into a MongoDB
>   database.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The following C++ code will connect to your local MongoDB server, and insert a BSON document into the **tutorial.persons** collection. The document created, has duplicate keys ("name" is used twice). When we query the collection for all persons and show the fields for each document, you will see that the "name" field occurs twice.

This proves that the C++ MongoDB driver is probably better suited to **insert** and **query** documents that use the same field name more than once.

```cpp
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"
#include <iostream>

void show_all_persons(mongo::DBClientConnection & c) {
    // Iterate over the collection in which we've just inserted the person object
    std::auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("tutorial.persons", mongo::BSONObj());
    while (cursor->more()) {
        mongo::BSONObj d = cursor->next();
        std::cout   << "The document " 
                    << d.toString() 
                    << " contains " << d.nFields() << " field(s)."
                    << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
  try {
    // Connect
    mongo::DBClientConnection c;
    c.connect("localhost");    
    // Prepare BSON "person" document to insert (notice duplicate key "name")
    mongo::BSONObj p = BSON( "name" << "Alice" << "name" << "Bob" );
    c.insert("tutorial.persons", p);        
    show_all_persons(c);
  } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the output when you run the code above once:

```
The document { _id: ObjectId('52e282cd84a7df0a1975eb8b'), name: "Alice", name: "Bob" } contains 3 field(s).
```

You can use this hacky CMakeLists.txt file for compilation:

```
project(bsoncpp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(bsoncpp ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(bsoncpp /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto)
```

I hope this helps. Now it is up to you to remove the undesired duplicate field.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the code an my answer to my question *2) How can I prevent the situation in the first place?* is: Use a combination of method *Mongo::Collection::update* and operation *$set*.

Example code:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
db = mongo_client.db("mydb")
coll = db.collection("test")
coll.remove

#create an entry
customer = {:id => 321, :name => "test customer"}
coll.save customer

#Now comes the important part! find the entry and modify it
coll.update({:id => 321}, {"$set" => {:name => "test customer 2"}}, {})
```

Comment: That's good to know. Coming from SQL, where you have a fixed table layout, I didn't expect that you can add fields with the same name. Great answer!